Is there a way to add a directory in a DDev container outside of the project directory?
I'm hoping to be able to store some secrets in the same directory structure that would be used by an Acquia Cloud IDE so that the same script can sync secrets in a Cloud IDE as in the DDev container per https://docs.acquia.com/secrets.

Stackoverflow is more suited for DDev questions. Moreover, you may also ask on the Discord support channel, the mantainers are super-nice and fast to give support.

I ended up adding a file at .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile.secrets that did the trick. This allows me to add a composer script that syncs a secrets.settings.php file to that Acquia-specific directory. No secrets are checked into git, but my developers can quickly grab the secrets when the need them.
# Create the secrets directory and set permissions
# These additions will be appended last to ddev's own Dockerfile
RUN mkdir -p /mnt/gfs/mysite.ide/nobackup && chmod 664 /mnt/gfs/mysite.ide/nobackup

In the extra:scripts section of composer.json, I have "acquia:secret": "./scripts/secrets.sh", and the secrets.sh looks like:
#!/bin/bash

# Sync secrets.settings.php from mysite.dev.
# Usage: ./scripts/secrets.sh [cd]

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    envid='mysite.ide'
else
    cd="$1"
    envid="mysite.ode$cd"
fi

envdir="/mnt/gfs/$envid"
echo "Downloading secrets from mysite.dev..."
scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -pr mysite.dev@mysitedev.ssh.prod.acquia-sites.com:/mnt/gfs/mysite.dev/nobackup $envdir

if [ -n "$cd" ]; then
    envid="mysite.$cd"
    echo "Uploading secrets to mysite.ode$cd..."
    scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -pr /mnt/gfs/local/nobackup mysite.ode$cd@mysiteode$cd.ssh.prod.acquia-sites.com:/mnt/gfs/mysite.ode$cd
fi

